# Change character to asterisk while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a field that convert some part of the string to asterisk..
the first four and last four is not converted only the other characters. so when I reach the fifth character it will be converted and when it reach the 10th character it will be normal again, the string length is 13. My problem with my code is I cant get that kind of process.

Hope you help me.

Thanks.

```js
function asteriskCard(string) {
    var lastfour = string.substr(string.length - 4);
    var firstfour = string.substr(0, 4);

    return firstfour + ' ***** ' + lastfour;
}

$('input').keyup(function(){
    $('div').text(asteriskCard($(this).val()))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div></div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend providing a JSFiddle with this kind of question.

Comment: @NielsNet he provided a snippet. Much better to keep it here

Comment: @Armin That was not what was asked.

Comment: Mark, can you show what expected output is? That the stars do not appear until the 5th char is entered?

Comment: Give us an example of what you want to get in the end please

Comment: @carsten made it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I think its what your looking for.

```
function asteriskCard(string) {
  var lastfour = string.length > 8 ? string.substr(string.length - (string.length - 9)) : "";
  var firstfour = string.substr(0, 4);
  var dots = '*****'.substring(0,string.length - 4);
  var total = (firstfour) + (dots.length > 0 ? ' ' + dots + ' ' : dots) + (lastfour);
  return total;
}

$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('div').text(asteriskCard($(this).val()))
});
```

**demo**

```js
function asteriskCard(string) {
  var lastfour = string.length > 8 ? string.substr(string.length - (string.length - 9)) : "";
  var firstfour = string.substr(0, 4);
  var dots = '*****'.substring(0,string.length - 4);
  var total = (firstfour) + (dots.length > 0 ? ' ' + dots + ' ' : dots) + (lastfour);
  return total;
}

$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('div').text(asteriskCard($(this).val()))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="13">
<div></div>
```

Comment: this is close sir, but the asterisk will only show if when im on the fifth character it will show one by one

Comment: @Mark try it now